# PHP: How to find out the position of a value in an array?

Tags: php

How to find out that foo is at the position of 2?: array('boo', 'moo', 'foo');

Comment: I hope you were asking of the key, not the "position"

Answer (score 10):

```
$key = array_search("foo", $array);
```

Answer (score 4):

> print_r ( array_search (
>   'value',$array_from ) );

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find the keys for all occurences of 'foo' (if you know there will be duplicates) then use:

```
$result = array_keys( $yourArray, 'foo' );
```

This will return an array with all corresponding keys. You see, `array_search` will only return the key of the first occurence. Be aware of this.